# Python can't find PDF file in same directory as script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, filesystems

I am writing a program to open PDF files and extract email addresses, but I am for some reason unable to open PDF files, as they are not found. Below is the code to locate and open the file:

```
filePath = os.getcwd()
#Start Function
def extractEmail(userInput):
    #Create object out of file that the user opens, instruct it to read binaries
    fileObj = open(filePath +"\\"+userInput, 'rb')
```

When I plug a pdf file (that is in the correct directory) in the userInput variable, it gives me the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\Work\\MyWorkplace\\Documents\\DateOfThing\\EmailSender\\TestDoc.pdf'
```

Comment: And you are sure that this folder structure and file exists?

Comment: Make sure the pdf is not locked, or password locked. Make sure it is in that folder. Also make sure your accepting the pdf on your python script.